# log4j limit log file's size

Tags: java, log4j

How should I configure `log4j.properties` to move log file that exceeds the limit to another directory?

For example: 
I have now log file in `/logs/` directory, that is 900kb size. After some time log becomes 1MB size and it should be moved in to another directory, let's say `/19.06.2018/` and should be renamed to `19.06.2018.log1` (19.06.2018 <-- current date)

But new log file in /logs/ directory should appear.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for below configuration:

```
log4j.appender.FILE.MaxFileSize=1MB
log4j.appender.FILE.DatePattern='.' yyyy-MM-dd-a
log4j.appender.FILE.MaxBackupIndex=15
log4j.appender.base.rollingPolicy.ActiveFileName=/logs/log-%i.log
log4j.appender.base.rollingPolicy.FileNamePattern=/logs/archive/log-%i.log.gz
```

Comment: There should be /logs/{current-date}/log-%i.log.gz file. New directory with the name of current date in 'yyyy-MM-dd' format. Anyway, thanks for a try!